# UItableviewcontroller cell text label content not displayed

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I ve successfully parsed json file in my app but when i tried to display all it in table view its not getting displayed .here is my code.

```
NSString *urlstr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://minora.p41techdev.net/portal.php"];

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlstr];

NSData *data =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSError *error;

NSArray *json=(NSMutableArray*) [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

//NSLog(@"%@",json);
NSDictionary *dict =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a title", @"more data",nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"titleKey",@"dataKey", nil]];


NSLog(@"1");

NSString *integ = [dict valueForKey:@"id"];
NSString *title=[dict valueForKey:@"title"];
NSString *category=[dict valueForKey:@"category"];
NSString *description=[dict valueForKey:@"description"];
NSString *spectitle=[dict valueForKey:@"spectitle"];
NSString *specvalue=[dict valueForKey:@"specvalue"];

NSArray *arr =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:integ,title,category,description,spectitle,specvalue, nil];

[tablearray addObject:arr];    
NSLog(@"%@",tablearray);





}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
//#warning Incomplete method implementation.
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [tablearray count];
NSLog(@"5");

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    cell.textLabel.text=[[tablearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:1];   


    return cell;
```

}

and my json file looks like this

```
[
{
    "id": "1",
    "category": "New Category1",
    "title": "New Product2",
    "description": "Please type a description1",
    "imgurl": "http://s.wordpress.org/about/images/wordpress-logo-notext-bg.png",
    "spectitle": "Specification",
    "specvalue": "Value"
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "category": "Mobile",
    "title": "Samsung",
    "description": "Please type a description",
    "imgurl": "http://s.wordpress.org/about/images/wordpress-logo-notext-bg.png",
    "spectitle": "Price",
    "specvalue": "100$"
}
]
```

Guidance please...

i'm getting thread issue like this

```
2012-07-20 19:36:03.504 tablevc[2253:f803] 1
2012-07-20 19:36:03.505 tablevc[2253:f803] 2
2012-07-20 19:36:03.507 tablevc[2253:f803] 4
2012-07-20 19:36:03.507 tablevc[2253:f803] 3
2012-07-20 19:36:03.508 tablevc[2253:f803] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1914.84/UITableView.m:6061
2012-07-20 19:36:03.508 tablevc[2253:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x13d2022 0x1563cd6 0x137aa48 0x9b32cb 0xb6d28 0xb73ce 0xa2cbd 0xb16f1 0x5ad21 0x13d3e42    0x1d8a679 0x1d94579 0x1d194f7 0x1d1b3f6 0x1d1aad0 0x13a699e 0x133d640 0x13094c6 0x1308d84  0x1308c9b 0x12bb7d8 0x12bb88a 0x1c626 0x2ae2 0x2a55 0x1)
 terminate called throwing an exception
```

Comment: Do you know that `tablearray` has the correct info in it? `NSLog` your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and make sure that it's 1) getting called and 2) `tablearray` is legit.

Comment: Could you put a print of the tablearray?

Comment: NO the table array didnot print..can u help me please..

Comment: I was talking of the array, NSLog(@"%@", tablearray);

Comment: ya i used that but its not getting printed....i think tablearray is not getting the value from arr..

Comment: @JavierBeltrán:can u find out why its not getting contents from arr?

Comment: So it hasn't been inited, do it like @stavash said in his answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14193/discussion-between-dany-and-javier-beltran)

Comment: but in this line i cant modify to my requirement since i'm new to ios NSDictionary *dict =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a title", @"more data",nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"titleKey",@"dataKey"]];

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the initialization of tablearray anywhere.

Add this to your viewDidLoad method:

```
tablearray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

I also see that you're inserting an array within an array. This means that when you need to access the correct data (NSString in your case), you must use the correct index:

```
cell.textLabel.text=[[tablearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:1];
```

I used "objectAtIndex:1" because the title string is stored at index 1 in the inner array. A better, more generic approach would be to use NSDictionary. For example:

```
NSDictionary *dict =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a title", @"more data",nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"titleKey",@"dataKey"]];
```

Also, make sure your delegate returns the correct amount of sections for your table.

Comment: itsin .h file i've declared as NSMutableArray *tablearray;

Comment: @property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *tablearray;

Comment: @Dany you have to allocate the tablearray: `tablearray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

Comment: now i got signal sigabart issue after initiating NSMutable array

Comment: Add exception breakpoints and see where this is happening. This is commonly caused by trying to access an index that's out of bounds.

Comment: tks for your answer but still i'm getting same error...Can u Checkout my edited code..That may helps you to find out my prob...

Comment: I don't see any change in obtaining the title NSString. What have you changed?

Comment: i'm getting this kind of thread as per ur suggestion Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14194/discussion-between-dany-and-stavash)

Answer (score 2):

Number of sections in tableview is at least one...

```
  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
    //#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;//It should be at least one.......
    }
```

Write the following code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. Otherwise you will get error.

```
if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Comment: tks for your answer but still i'm getting same error...Can u Checkout my edited code..That may helps you to find out my prob...

Answer (score 1):

call `[tableView reloadData]` after you add arr in your table array...

```
[tablearray addObject:arr];
[tableView reloadData]
NSLog(@"2");
```

hope it helps

Comment: but i dint declare any tableview because i had created new file under UItableViewController...Any idea to rework on code..?

Comment: tks for your answer but still i'm getting same error...Can u Checkout my edited code..That may helps you to find out my prob...

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize the cell like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[tablearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: The same issue or a different one?

Comment: Same issue...contents not getting displayed..Since i'm passing many values to be displayed in a single cell.Whether it will resize automatically or shall i have to set it..

Answer (score 1):

You have tablarray with 1 element. This element is an array containing a few entries.
Your data source declares only one cell (tablearray count, which is one).

Your cellForIndexPath method will always look for the first and only the first element in the json array anyway.

Edit: unrelated, but if a field in your json is not set, you'll get nil back, and that'll terminate your array in arrayWithObjects, which will likely cause an out of bounds index down the line.
Be *very* careful with this method, it's very easy to shoot yourself in the foot with it.